# Buscar índices dentro de array PHP

Tags: php, array, indices

Tengo un array generado a traves de JSON el cúal obtengo de la respuesta que me entrega el consumo de una API, dicho arreglo tiene la siguiente información a manera de ejemplo:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [idRate] => 2564864
                        [idProduct] => 34
                        [product] => Express
                        [vehicle] => bike
                        [idCarrier] => 10
                        [carrier] => 99 MINUTOS
                        [total] => 95.65
                        [deliveryDays] => 1
                        [deliveryType] => Domicilio
                        [quotationType] => EnvioClick Pro
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [idRate] => 996246
                        [idProduct] => 29
                        [product] => Econu00f3mico
                        [vehicle] => 
                        [idCarrier] => 21
                        [carrier] => CARSSA_EC
                        [total] => 121.61
                        [deliveryDays] => 6
                        [deliveryType] => Domicilio
                        [quotationType] => EnvioClick Pro
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [idRate] => 2564858
                        [idProduct] => 15
                        [product] => Econu00f3mico
                        [vehicle] => 
                        [idCarrier] => 7
                        [carrier] => REDPACK
                        [total] => 188.22
                        [deliveryDays] => 2
                        [deliveryType] => Domicilio
                        [quotationType] => EnvioClick Pro
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [idRate] => 2564856
                        [idProduct] => 11
                        [product] => Dos du00edas
                        [vehicle] => 
                        [idCarrier] => 6
                        [carrier] => ESTAFETA
                        [total] => 263.62
                        [deliveryDays] => 2
                        [deliveryType] => Domicilio
                        [quotationType] => EnvioClick Pro
                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [idRate] => 2564854
                        [idProduct] => 12
                        [product] => Express
                        [vehicle] => 
                        [idCarrier] => 6
                        [carrier] => ESTAFETA
                        [total] => 286.01
                        [deliveryDays] => 1
                        [deliveryType] => Domicilio
                        [quotationType] => EnvioClick Pro
                    )

                [6] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [idRate] => 2564863
                        [idProduct] => 21
                        [product] => Express
                        [vehicle] => 
                        [idCarrier] => 9
                        [carrier] => DHL
                        [total] => 298.32
                        [deliveryDays] => 1
                        [deliveryType] => Domicilio
                        [quotationType] => EnvioClick Pro
                    )
            )
```

Lo que no puedo hacer es buscar el número de indice para un dato en concreto, por ejemplo si quiero buscar cuantos elementos satisfacen una condición dada como deliveryDays=1. HE tratado con array_search dentro de un bucle while, pero solo me devuelve el primer elemento el numero de veces que itire while.

Hay alguna forma de obtener dicha información?

Comment: Trate con esta función, pero aún no me arroja el resultado esperado:  $rastrea = [];
foreach ($decode as $key) {
 if (in_array($this->deliveryDays->'1', $prueba)) {
  array_push($rastrea, $item);
 }
}

Comment: es obligatorio utilizar alguno de esas funciones (in_array, o parecido)? o la búsqueda que requieres es porque podrías buscar por cualquier atributo del json? Por otra parte si necesitas buscar `deliveryDays == 1` cual es el resultado esperado (un array con los object que cumplan la condicion)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es buscar el índice dentro del arreglo de acuerdo a una condición, puedes hacerlo así:

```
$rastrea = array();
foreach ($arreglo as $key => $objeto) {
    if ($objeto->deliveryDays == 1) {
        $rastrea[] = $key;
    }
}
print_r($rastrea);
```

En este caso estoy usando los datos que dejaste en el comentario, donde `$arreglo` es la variable con los datos obtenidos de la API.

Con `foreach ($arreglo as $key => $objeto)` ponemos en dos variables temporales el índice (`$key`) y los datos del objeto (`$objeto`), entonces ya dentro de la función puedes acceder a los datos del objeto  y compararlos con algún valor recibido o definido por ti (`$objeto->deliveryDays == 1`), y como en cada iteración obtenemos también el índice, podemos almacenarlo en otro array `$rastrea[] = $key`, mostrarlo o lo que necesitemos.

Puedes consultar la información de como usar `foreach` en [PHP:foreach - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Excelente, no había considerado la opción que me mostraste.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizas la función `array_multisort()`.

**Ejemplo:**

```php
$datos={json}
foreach($datos as $id => $fila){
    $deliveryDays[$id]=$fila["deliveryDays"];
}
array_multisort($deliveryDays,SORT_ASC,$datos);
print_r($datos);
```

En [PHP.NET -> `array_multisort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-multisort.php) hay un [ejemplo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-multisort.php#example-6002) parecido

**Razón para utilizar `array_multisort()`**

La ventaja de `array_multisort` es que puedes ordenar con varios elementos distintos, respetando un orden (Por ejemplo que ordene por cantidad y si tienen la misma cantidad, ordena por nombre)

Comment: Revise esta función que comentas pero su característica es que solo ordena el array de manera ascendente o descendente y donde me atoré fue en buscar el índice de los objetos que dentro de sus valores tuvieran deliveryDays = 1.